# The given path's format is not supported C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, exception, c#-3.0, ranorex

```
static void cmd_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> found = new List<string>();
        string line;
        using(StreamReader file =  new StreamReader(e.Data))
        {
            while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if(line.Contains("Passed"))
                {
                    found.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (string Txt in found)
        {
            Report.Info("Output from other process");
            Report.Success(Txt);
        }
    }
```

Above code is giving the exception. The exception I'm getting.
`System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
   at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath
   at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList`

I running this C# code in ranorex test automation tool.

Comment: Does examining the offending path give any clues?

Comment: Check whether the path of the file is correct by debugging

Comment: The path of the file is correct I'm getting the correct output when I remove list and stream reader which I'm using to parse the output to search a line starting with passed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is a Ranorex issue. Which line in your code causes the error?